# How to pass multiple button click event from child to parent in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, parent-child

- I have 18 buttons on the child form "Control Test" which send event to the parent form
- Out of 18 buttons, 14 are  ON and OFF functionality, making 7 pairs as in the picture
- The problem is raising the event for each button, it causes very long and messy code, both in the child and the parent form,
- Is there any less complex way to do it? like I have done with the menu.

Child Form:
[image]

Child Form:

```cs
// B Plus Relay On Button
public event EventHandler BPRElayOnBtnClicked;
protected virtual void WhenBPRelayOnBtnClicked(EventArgs e)
{
    BPRElayOnBtnClicked.Invoke(this, e);
}
private void BPRelayOn_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WhenBPRelayOnBtnClicked(e);
}

    // B Plus Relay OFF Button
public event EventHandler BPRElayOffBtnClicked; 
protected virtual void WhenBPRelayOffBtnClicked(EventArgs e)
{
    BPRElayOnBtnClicked.Invoke(this, e);
}
private void BPRelayOff_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WhenBPRelayOffBtnClicked(e);
}



// B Minus Relay ON Button
public event EventHandler BMRElayOnBtnClicked;
protected virtual void WhenBMRelayOnBtnClicked(EventArgs e)
{
    BMRElayOnBtnClicked.Invoke(this, e);
}

private void BMRelayOn_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WhenBMRelayOnBtnClicked(e);
}

// B Minus Relay OFF Button
public event EventHandler BMRElayOffBtnClicked;
protected virtual void WhenBMRelayOffBtnClicked(EventArgs e)
{
    BMRElayOffBtnClicked.Invoke(this, e);
}

private void BMRelayOff_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WhenBMRelayOffBtnClicked(e);
}
...... //event for each button
```

Parent Form:

```cs
private void viewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem menu = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

    switch (menu.Name)
    {
               
        case "controlTestToolStripMenuItem":
            if (Application.OpenForms["CtrlTest"] is CtrlTest ctrlTest)
            {
                ctrlTest.Focus();
                return;
            }
            ctrlTest = new CtrlTest();
            ctrlTest.BPRElayOnBtnClicked += CtrlTest_BPRElayOnBtnClicked;
            ctrlTest.BPRElayOffBtnClicked += CtrlTest_BPRElayOffBtnClicked;
            ctrlTest.BMRElayOnBtnClicked += CtrlTest_BMRElayOnBtnClicked;
            ctrlTest.BMRElayOffBtnClicked += CtrlTest_BMRElayOffBtnClicked;
            ctrlTest.PreRElayOnBtnClicked += CtrlTest_PreRElayOnBtnClicked;
            ctrlTest.PreRElayOffBtnClicked += CtrlTest_PreRElayOffBtnClicked;
            ctrlTest.MdiParent = this;
            ctrlTest.Show();
            break;
            .........//Other menus ...
        default:
            break;
private void CtrlTest_BPRElayOnBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something here
}
private void CtrlTest_BPRElayOffBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something here
}
private void CtrlTest_BMRElayOnBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something here
}
private void CtrlTest_BMRElayOffBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something here
}
```

Comment: Just have one event handler for all clicked events and within that test the value of Sender to decide on action.  Much the same code but at least all in one place, which is may be more manageable

Comment: Don't use a `Button` in the first place. Use a `CheckBox` and set its `Appearance` property to `Button`. It will then look like a regular `Button` but it will have depressed and released states corresponding to the `Checked` property having a value of `True` and `False`.

Comment: @JonRoberts Thank you for your suggestion. If it is within just one form I can easily do it like I have done it to menuItem, If you don't mind Can you give me an example?

Comment: @John Thank You for your suggestion. Well, at least I don't have to make two different event handler methods for on and off. I am curious how does actually the Checkbox as a button works, Can you share with me a link for a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `on/off`, take a look at the following [control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1029499/ToggleSwitch-Winforms-Control). For the others setup one event and work out logic similar to the `on/off` buttons.

Download the source, add the class project to your Visual Studio solution. Open the class project and change the .NET Framework currently set to 4, to your project's .NET Framework version.

Setup an enum where for each on/off button set it's tag to one of the members. this ways things are clearer using a switch and enums.

```
public enum OperationType
{
    BPlusRelay,
    BMinusRelay,
    PreRelay,
    CycleCount,
    PairDown,
    TestMode,
    StandbyMode
}
```

In the child form, setup and event and set tags for each on/off control. Change the names to reflect their purpose, I simply added them quickly for demoing purposes.

```
    public partial class ChildForm : Form
    {
        public delegate void OnClicked(OperationType operationType, bool state);
        public event OnClicked ClickedEvent;
        public ChildForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetProperties();
        }
    
        public void SetProperties()
        {
    
            ToggleSwitch1.Tag = OperationType.BPlusRelay;
            ToggleSwitch2.Tag = OperationType.BMinusRelay;
            ToggleSwitch3.Tag = OperationType.PreRelay;
            ToggleSwitch4.Tag = OperationType.CycleCount;
            ToggleSwitch5.Tag = OperationType.PairDown;
            ToggleSwitch6.Tag = OperationType.TestMode;
            ToggleSwitch7.Tag = OperationType.StandbyMode;
    
            var list = Controls.OfType<JCS.ToggleSwitch>().ToList();
    
            foreach (var toggleSwitch in list)
            {
                toggleSwitch.CheckedChanged += ToggleSwitchOnCheckedChanged;
            }
        }
    
        private void ToggleSwitchOnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var current = (JCS.ToggleSwitch)sender;
            ClickedEvent?.Invoke((OperationType)current.Tag, current.Checked);
        }
    }
```

In the main form, show the child form, subscribe to the event above.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ShowChildFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        var childForm = new ChildForm();
        childForm.ClickedEvent += ClickedEvent;

        try
        {
            childForm.ShowDialog();
        }
        finally
        {
            childForm.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void ClickedEvent(OperationType operationType, bool state)
    {
        switch (operationType)
        {
            case OperationType.BPlusRelay:
                // TODO
                break;
            case OperationType.BMinusRelay:
                // TODO
                break;
            case OperationType.PreRelay:
                // TODO
                break;
            case OperationType.CycleCount:
                // TODO
                break;
            case OperationType.PairDown:
                // TODO
                break;
            case OperationType.TestMode:
                // TODO
                break;
            case OperationType.StandbyMode:
                // TODO
                break;

        }


    }
}
```

Partly done form, and note you can change the size of the buttons.

[image]

Comment: So far this code is working very fine and also thanks to you I am also able to create my own customer toggle button. I have also added hover and some other events. But I am not able to make a specific event on "ON" and "OFF" in the parent form 
`case OperationType.BMinusRelay: if (state.Equals(ON)) {//TODO } else  {//TODO }`

Comment: See the following [code sample](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/closet-code/tree/master/ToggleSwitchDemo)

Comment: @KarenPanne Thank You so much. I just started learning c# and straight away jumped into a very challenging project causing myself a lot of trouble. I really do admire you and other people who are making others' pain a little less painful. If you don't mind, can I ask for your recommendation on some good resources that I can refer to while practising it.

Comment: Best resource is [PluralSight](https://www.pluralsight.com/) and [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/)